# Other Application Cartridges availability in Openshift Origin

Tags: openshift-origin

I was able to install the default cartridges bundled in Origin,,

What if I need to add some application like ex: httpd server, ldap server, tomcat etc..

Is there a way to do it, I saw the DIY and customer cartridge install, is there any pointers on how to use those?

Regards
G

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your question is 100% clear.  If you are trying to install downloadable cartridges, you should be able to use the same syntax that you use for online, something like:

```
rhc app create jekyll https://raw.github.com/openshift-cartridges/openshift-jekyll-cartridge/master/metadata/manifest.yml
```

If that is not what you are asking, can you be more specific about what you are trying to do, and what you have tried already and what errors it gave?